# Are there any journals in the area of humanities/media studies willing to publish translated articles?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

Two years ago I have published a scholarly book in Polish, which is my native language. While I'm relatively satisfied with its' reception in Poland, I'd like for it to also reach international academics. The director of my Department advised me to first try and publish one or more chapters as separate journal articles (the structure of the book allows for such partitions). I've already searched through quite a few respectable journals in my field (Humanities/media/television studies) and pretty much all of them look for "original, unpublished works". Should I infer that articles that were previously published in languages other than English, and thus are not available for English-speaking scholars, won't have any chance of being published? Are you aware of any journals that do publish translated articles, or should I just focus all my attention on putting out new, completely original research in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider sending emails to editors of the journals you want to target, asking their opinion on the matter. You want to submit to their journal a paper that has never been published in English before. This may be original and unpublished enough for their tastes.

Maybe they won't be interested, but it can't hurt to ask.